# Next.js Redirect внутри HOC

Tags: node.js, nextjs, next.js

Доброго времени суток!

Имею такой HOC:

```js
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import Router from 'next/router'
import Error from 'next/error'
import parseCookies from './parseCookies'

export default function (Component) {
    return class checkAuth extends Component {
        static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
            let cookies = parseCookies(ctx.req);

            console.log(cookies);

            let check = false;

            if (cookies.token) {
                let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/admin/check`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                    body: new URLSearchParams(`token=${cookies.token}`)
                })
                if (response.ok) {
                    const request = await response.json();
                    if (request.values.admin == 1) {
                        check = true
                    }
                    else {
                        check = false
                    }
                }
                else {
                    new Cookies().remove('token');
                    check = false
                }
            }
            else { new Cookies().remove('token'); check = false }

            return { check }

        }

        renderProtectedPage = () => {
            try {
                const { check, res } = this.props;

                if (check) {
                    return (
                        <Component {...this.props} />
                    )
                }
                if (!check) {
                    return (Router.push('/login')) // редирект происходит но выдает ошибку
                }
                else {
                    return (<Error statusCode={404} />)
                }
            }
            catch {
                return <Error statusCode={404} />
            }
        }
        render() {
            return this.renderProtectedPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Редирект происходит но я получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь в редиректе!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!check) {
  Router.push('/login');
  return null
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]